# Update Google Sheets script to automatically pull reference from new daily tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently working on a spreadsheet that automatically duplicates and renames tabs to match each new day. This end result are tabs in the format of "12/05 SF" or "12/05 NYC". One of the central daily tabs references cells in the other city-specific ones via index match. Because the dates are strings rather than text, I don't know how to update the 12/05 references to 12/06, and so on for each new day:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=index(\'12/05 SF\'!C6:C6,match("3a",\'12/05 SF\'!C3:C3,0))');
```

I see myself as having two options:

1. Figure out how to write a script that allows dynamic changing of the formula above
2. Rename the daily sheets to just "SF" and "NYC" so I don't have to update the formula

I've unsuccessfully tried to update the macro formulas to use a dynamic date for each tab rather than the static 12/05 date.

Comment: I can understand your output data but not clear about what's the input data like. Can you give more detailed examples for the src sheet?

Comment: My tabs are automatically refreshed each day with the new date. So "12/07 SF" becomes "12/08 SF", "12/07 LA" becomes "12/08 LA" and so on, while copies for prior dates are archived. I would like to still keep today's date in the active tabs instead of just "SF" and "LA", but I don't know how to IMPORTRANGE data from a tab name that is constantly changing.

Comment: For example, =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxx","12/07 SF!d6") ...... Since the tab name is being put in as text, I don't know how to keep the formula dynamic and the date changes. Does that make sense? @CharlesHan

Answer (score 1):

To get the current date formatted as `MM/dd` you might use `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MM/dd')`.

Example:

```
const cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'MM/dd');
const formula = `=index('${date} SF'!C6:C6,match("3a",'${date} SF'!C3:C3,0))`;
cell.setFormulaR1C1(formula);
```

Note: the `formula` declaration use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).